# TeeChart for .NET v2014 WPF with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, wpf, teechart

Is TeeChart (Steema) for .NET v2014 WPF, can be supported by .NET 3.5?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 2):

You can read from its release notes that .NET 3.5 is still supported even in TeeChart for .NET version 2014,

http://www.steema.com/versioninfo/net

For more inquiries, please contact Steema support,

http://www.steema.com/licensing/support/?steema/licensing_support

Comment: A general question according to .NET version, if I open a new project on Microsoft Studion with on a specific .NET version, Can I change it during an exist project to another version or should I open a new one with another .NET version? By the way, I'm using an evaluated version of TeeChart 2014, so I can't post on their support forum. Thanks.

Comment: Contact their presale by email please. If you have any general question, post it separately or search within StackOverflow.com.